# Meaning behind "Doing otherwise" in context to the previous sentence

Tags: phrases

I have asked a similar question before, but I would confirmation from the pros.

I do not know of all the resources you use, instead I usually just search in google with quotation marks to get an idea of what is correct. I found a few examples online but not enough for assurance.

Are the following statements logically correct?

- Do not touch the glass. **Doing otherwise** may cause injury.
- Do not mix paints. **Doing otherwise** may cause a malfunction.

Or do they need to be written as follows:

- Do not touch the glass. **Doing so** may cause injury
- Do not mix paints. **Doing so** may cause a malfunction.

According to the definition of "otherwise", is either way acceptable and do they mean the same thing?

(From Oxford Languages)

*otherwise*

*1.in circumstances different from those present or considered; or else.*

*3. in a different way.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find those statements incorrect or, at best, ambiguous. (Doing otherwise than touching the glass or than not touching it?)

I suggest either *Do not do this. Doing so may cause a problem*

or *Avoid doing this. Doing otherwise may cause a problem.*

So, if you want to use *otherwise*, I would recommend something like:

> Keep hands away from glass. Doing otherwise may cause injury.
>
> Use only paints supplied by the manufacturer. Doing otherwise may
> cause a malfunction.

Comment: Yes, *doing otherwise* after a negative is a double negative: "Or if you don't don't..."

Answer (score 0):

"Doing otherwise" makes both statements logically correct in this context. "Doing otherwise" means "doing differently", so to do otherwise when you are instructed not to do something means to do that something.

The 'Doing so" construction may be understood by many English speakers to have the same meaning, but it is not logically correct in this context. "Doing so" when you are instructed not to do something means not to do that something.